# Want a SQL statement to count number

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table have 3 columns id, open_time, close_time, the data looks like this:

[image]

then I want a SQL to get result like this:
[image]

the rule is : if the date equals to open time then New, if the date > open_time and date < close_time then Open, if the date equals close_time then Closed

how can I write the SQL in Oracle?

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: I have no idea about how to write this SQL

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Please edit your question and replace the images with text (which should be rather easy; just copy & paste).

Answer (score 1):

First build a table on-the-fly containing all dates from the minimum date in the table until today. You need a recursive query for this.

Then build a table on-the-fly for the three statuses.

Now cross join the two to get all combinations. These are the rows you want.

The rest is counting per day and status, which can be achieved with a join and grouping or with one or more subqueries. I'm showing the join:

```
with days(day) as 
(
  select min(open_time) as day from opentimes
  union all
  select day + 1 from days where day < trunc(sysdate)
)
, statuses as
(
  select 'New' as status, 1 as sortkey from dual
  union all
  select 'Open' as status, 2 as sortkey from dual
  union all
  select 'Close' as status, 3 as sortkey from dual
)
select
  d.day, 
  s.status,
  count(case when (s.status = 'New' and d.day = o.open_time)
               or (s.status = 'Open' and d.day = o.close_time)
               or (s.status = 'Close' and d.day > cls.open_time and d.day < cls.close_time)
             then 1 end) as cnt
from days d
cross join statuses s
join opentimes o on d.day between o.open_time and o.close_time
group by d.day, s.status
order by d.day, max(s.sortkey);
```